# How would I show a notification when the timer hits 0 while the user is in the background of my app?

Tags: swift, timer

I have this timer and when the 10 min are over I would like to show a notification while the user is in the background. The problem Im having is when the app is in the background the notification never gets called after the 10 min. I am able to get the timer to countdown once I leave the app but can't get the notification func to get called once the timer hits 0. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
var timeCount2:TimeInterval = 600 //seconds
var timer: Timer!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    backgroundTimer() // timer begins to countdown here

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enterForeground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    
}


 func backgroundTimer() {
    
    var bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0)
        bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        })

    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateStopWatch4), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .default)
 }

var fgTime = Int()
var backgroundTime = Int()    

@objc func enterForeground(){
            
    ///initial time
    let foregroundTime = self.currentBackgroundDate.timeIntervalSince(NSDate() as Date)
   
    
    ///turns foreground timer to integer
    fgTime = Int(foregroundTime)
   
    ///subtracts the bg from fg
    let diffrence = backgroundTime - fgTime
    
    ///once returned to app the timer will be updated
    timeCount2 -= Double(diffrence)
    
    print("This is the seconds off when first leaving app and then entering \(diffrence)")

}


@objc func enterBackground(){
            
    let bgTime = currentBackgroundDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
    
    backgroundTime = Int(bgTime) // turns to integer
    
    print("app is in the background")
}

     func timeStringForScore4(_ time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i %02i", minutes, seconds)
}
    
@objc func updateStopWatch4() {
    
    self.timeCount2 -= 1
    playTimer.text = timeStringForScore4(timeCount2)

    if timeCount2 == 0  {
        
    callNotification() //shows notification in background when timer hits 0
}
```

Comment: Look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger

Comment: To make jnpdx's answer a bit clearer: you won't use a timer at all. You'll just set a single user notification for the time you want it go off. You don't need to count seconds. You know when the alert needs to happen.

Comment: Okay I get thank you!

Comment: @RobNapier, you should post your response as an answer. I was going to say the same thing in an answer but you beat me to it. Since you were the first to state it clearly, you should post the canonical answer.

Comment: @DuncanC Agreed. Added as answer.

Comment: @RobNapier did you forget to tap the submit button? (I don't see your answer.)

Comment: I don't know what happened. You must be right and I didn't hit submit. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't use a timer at all. You'll just set a single [user notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter) for the time you want it go off. You don't need to count seconds. You know when the alert needs to happen.